# Proof of small part of Euclid's proof of pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry

Geometry proofs have never been my strongest point, case in point the following: I need to proof that the surface of half of the small square (second picture) is equal to the triangle in the first picture.

[image: WhatToDoHere]

Is this a theorem, an axiom, postulate, ...? And what is it called, so I can use it for future reference? Part of my problem is that I don't know how to name it, so I can't look for it either.

Comment: For the shaded triangle on the left, find the area using the bottom of the small square as the base.

Comment: Both triangles have the same base with equal altitude. This means they have the same area.

Comment: If two triangles have the same base and height, they have the same area. (Here, the bottom-left side of square a is the base.)

Comment: As for a name: [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) is a general version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here a figure to illustrate the comment of   @columbus8myhw .
The area of the two triangles is $AA' \times AB = AA' \times A''B''$, and the triangles are limited by parallel lines, exactly as stated by the Cavalieri's principle.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the area is

$$ \frac{1}{2} base \cdot height $$ for all triangles with vertex sliding parallel to base and

$$  base \cdot height $$ for all parallelograms, the parallel side sliding similarly.

"Parallel" means that the height remains same.